# invalid input: qMulZeil uses a 6th argument, N, which is missing

Tags: maple

1. do not know how to solve

   RE1 := sumtoolshyperrecursion;
   rsolve(RE1);
2. then change to use qMulZeil get error, already has N, got error

   Hahn := hyperterm([-n,n+a+b-1,-x],[a,-N],1,k);
   qMulZeil(Hahn,[a,b],n,N,{});

   > Hahn := hyperterm([-n, n+a+b-1, -x], [a, -N], 1, k); 
   >   qMulZeil(Hahn, [i, j], n, N, {});
   >
   > ### pochhammer(-n, k) pochhammer(n + a + b - 1, k) pochhammer(-x, k)

   ```
       pochhammer(a, k) pochhammer(-N, k) factorial(k)
   ```

   Error, invalid input: qMulZeil uses a 6th argument, N, which is missing
3. After tried demo http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/multiZ/qmZ/inqmZ1, also get error

   qMulZeil(qfac(n)/qfac(i)/qfac(j)/qfac(n-i-j),q^i+q^j,binomial(i,2)+binomial(j,2),[i,j],n,N,{});

   > qMulZeil(qfac(n)/(qfac(i)*qfac(j)*qfac(n-i-j)), q^i+q^j, binomial(i, 2)+binomial(j, 2), [i, j], n, N, {});
   >                              Bad input
   >                  FAIL[1], [FAIL[2][1], FAIL[2][2]]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using the third-party package qMultiZeilberger, where the procedure qMulZeil is defined as [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/qMultiZeilberger).

But that procedure specifies seven arguments, and your codes call only passes five. So the error message is complaining about the first (sixth) missing argument.

This is not part of stock Maple. If you understand how that third-party procedure is supposed to work, then try passing it two more (appropriate) arguments.

Comment: not sure how to use, follow demo example http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/multiZ/qmZ/inqmZ1  also get error

Comment: can not find this function in Maple, so i use this third party package